# How to handle error in an async function with multiple await functions?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have the example from my code down below I want to reduce the code so it lose the bad state that it has now I am new to async await and i dont want to use try and catch. there is the other way but I cannot do the syntax

```js
const UpdateData = async (selected: any) => {
    // Clients
    const docRefClients = doc(db, 'Data', _authContext.currentUser.uid);
    let arr: any = [];
    // Get The doc
    await getDoc(docRefClients)
      .then((docSnap) => {
        arr = docSnap.data()?.clients;
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        alert(errorCode);
      });
    const updateData = arr.map((el: any) => {
      if (el.clientId === selected.clientId) {
        return selected;
      }
    });
    console.log(updateData);
    // Modify
    await updateDoc(docRefClients, {
      clients: arr,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        alert(errorCode);
      });
  };
```

Comment: First of all you need to remove the `: any` from all your parameters that have that.  The correct way in JS is like: → `const UpdateData = async (selected) => `  → `let arr = [];`  →  `const updateData = arr.map((el) =>`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it using promises. See code below:

```
const handle = (promise) => {
  return promise
    .then(data => ([data, undefined]))
    .catch(error => Promise.resolve([undefined, error]));
}

const UpdateData = async (selected: any) => {
  // Clients
  const docRefClients = doc(db, 'Data', _authContext.currentUser.uid);
  let arr = [];
  // Get The doc
  let [get, getError] = await handle(getDoc(docRefClients));
    arr = docSnap.data()?.clients;
    console.log(arr);
    // Throws an error and handles it with promises
    if(getError) throw new Error('Could not fetch details');

  const updateData = arr.map((el) => {
    if (el.clientId === selected.clientId) {
      return selected;
    }
  });
  console.log(updateData);
  // Modify
  let [update, updateError] = await handle(updateDoc(docRefClients, {
    regions: arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
  }));
  console.log(update);
  // Throws an error and handles it with promises
  if(updateError) throw new Error('Could not update details');
};
```

The handle function takes a promise as an argument and always resolves it, returning an array with `[data|undefined, Error|undefined]`.

If the promise passed to the handle function resolves it returns `[data, undefined]`;
If it was rejected, the handle function still resolves it and returns `[undefined, Error]`.